# How to get email address of group member from LDAP using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, active-directory

I am trying to get the email addresses of AD group members of a particular LDAP group using python.

I have following code. The Print m statement writes something like below.

Output:

```
CN=Admin_abc20,OU=Admin ID's,OU=TEST1,DC=other_example,DC=example,DC=com
CN=leterd,OU=Employees,OU=BACD,DC=na,DC=example,DC=com
CN=mytest37,OU=Employees,OU=SUNPH,DC=na,DC=example,DC=com
CN=Doe Mestre\, John,OU=Partners &    Contractors,OU=TEST1,DC=other_example,DC=example,DC=com
CN=Robin\, Mark [ABCD],OU=Partners & Contractors,OU=JJCUS,DC=na,DC=example,DC=com
CN=San Irdondo\, Paul [TEST1 Non-ABC],OU=Partners & Contractors,OU=TEST1,DC=other_example,DC=example,DC=com
```

My Code:

```
def get_group_members(group_name, ad_conn, basedn=AD_USER_BASEDN):
   members = []
   ad_filter = AD_GROUP_FILTER.replace('My_Group_Name', group_name)
   result = ad_conn.search_s(basedn, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE, ad_filter)
      if result:
         if len(result[0]) >= 2 and 'member' in result[0][1]:
             members_tmp = result[0][1]['member']
             for m in members_tmp:
               print m
               #email = ad_conn.search_s(m, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(objectClass=*)',['mail'])
               #print email
```

Now when I remove comment from last 2 lines of my code to get the email address of persons, I get following error, please note that I have changed by company's ldap identifiers to example/test.

Can you please help me with this? I am a newbie to python.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/app/abc/python/Test_new.py", line 81, in <module>
group_members = get_group_members(group_name, ad_conn)
File "/app/abc/python/Test_new.py", line 58, in get_group_members
email = ad_conn.search_s(m, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(objectClass=*)',   ['mail'])
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 516, in search_s
return      self.search_ext_s(base,scope,filterstr,attrlist,attrsonly,None,None,timeout=self.timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 510, in search_ext_s
return self.result(msgid,all=1,timeout=timeout)[1]
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 436, in result
res_type,res_data,res_msgid = self.result2(msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 440, in result2
res_type, res_data, res_msgid, srv_ctrls = self.result3(msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 446, in result3
ldap_result = self._ldap_call(self._l.result3,msgid,all,timeout)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/ldap/ldapobject.py", line 96, in _ldap_call
result = func(*args,**kwargs)
ldap.REFERRAL: {'info': 'Referral:\nldap://ab.example.com/CN=Radfde3,OU=Partners%20&%20Contractors,OU=JANBE,DC=eu,DC=example,DC=com', 'desc': 'Referral'}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about Python but I think your problem is with the LDAP filter. Try this for the last 2 lines of code:

```
email = ad_conn.search_s(m, ldap.SCOPE_SUBTREE,'(&(objectClass=person)(mail=*))')
print email
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks Narsi Yatim, Still it is not pulling the email address information.